# Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'(npx react-native run-android issue)

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

After running npx react-native run-android i got the common issue "Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app".'
[image]

Following an advice i tried to do this https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android, but when i run:
`$ ./gradlew bundleRelease` from android directory i got: 
"Task 'bundleRelease' not found in root project 'MoscowForDummies'."

My gradle.properties:

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=Profit***
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=Profit***
```

Part of my build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.moscowfordummies"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

and my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Does anybody have any advice how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Besides `signingConfig` you have to have `buildTypes` as well in build.gradle(app) file:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```